# SQL to find if refund would be processed or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, they can be created with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(Id integer,ptime date, rtime date, sid text, itemid text, gtv integer);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(3,'2019-09-19',null,'a','a1',58);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(12,'2019-12-10','2019-12-15','b','b2',475);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(3,'2020-09-01','2020-09-02','f','f9',33);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(2,'2020-04-30',null,'d','d3',250);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(1,'2020-10-22',null,'f','f2',91);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(8,'2020-04-16',null,'e','e7',24);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(5,'2019-09-23',null,'g','g6',61);

CREATE TABLE Items(sid text , itemid text, category text, name text);

/* Create a few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Items VALUES('a','a1','pants','denimpants');
INSERT INTO Items VALUES('a','a2','tops','blouse');
INSERT INTO Items VALUES('f','f1','table','coffee table');
INSERT INTO Items VALUES('f','f5','chair','loungechair');
INSERT INTO Items VALUES('f','f6','chair','armchair');
INSERT INTO Items VALUES('d','d2','jewelry','bracelet');
INSERT INTO Items VALUES('b','b4','earphone','airpods');

Select * from NAMES;
COMMIT;
```

1. Create a flag in the transaction items table indicating whether the refund can be processed or not. The condition for a refund to be processed is that it has to happen within 72 of Purchase time.
   Expected Output: Only 1 of the three refunds would be processed in this case
2. Create a rank by buyer_id column in the transaction items table and filter for only the second purchase per
   buyer. (Ignore refunds here)
   Expected Output: Only the second purchase of buyer_id 3 should the output
3. How will you find the second transaction time per buyer (don’t use min/max; assume there were more
   transactions per buyer in the table)
   Expected Output: Only the second purchase of buyer_id along with a timestamp

I have been trying to wrap my head around this, but cant seem to understand where to start.

Comment: transaction items table ? There isn't such a named table published..

Comment: @P.Salmon I have edited the question.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? It sounds like asking for answers to a homework or interview question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test script treating the questions. NB I am running MariaDB. There may be adjustments needed for mySQL
We set up the database, written to be reusable.

```sql
USE test;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transactions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions(Id integer,ptime date, rtime date, sid text, itemid text, gtv integer);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(3,'2021-09-19',null,'a','a1',58);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(12,'2021-12-10','2022-03-15','b','b2',475);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(3,'2021-09-01','2021-09-02','f','f9',33);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(2,'2021-12-30',null,'d','d3',250);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(1,'2021-10-22',null,'f','f2',91);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(8,'2021-04-16',null,'e','e7',24);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(5,'2022-01-23',null,'g','g6',61);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(sid text , itemid varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY, category text, name text);
/* Create a few records in this table */
INSERT INTO items VALUES('a','a1','pants','denimpants');
INSERT INTO items VALUES('a','a2','tops','blouse');
INSERT INTO items VALUES('f','f1','table','coffee table');
INSERT INTO items VALUES('f','f5','chair','loungechair');
INSERT INTO items VALUES('f','f6','chair','armchair');
INSERT INTO items VALUES('d','d2','jewelry','bracelet');
INSERT INTO items VALUES('b','b4','earphone','airpods');
COMMIT;
Select * from transactions;
Select * from items;
```

Here we add a virtual column which gives us the refund status using the sales date and the request date.

> - request date before sales date = error
> - no request date = Not requested
> - request date 0 to 72 days after sales date = accepted
> - request date more then 72 days after sales date = too late

```
ALTER TABLE transactions ADD COLUMN refund VARCHAR(20) AS (CASE WHEN rtime is NULL THEN 'Not requested' WHEN rtime < ptime THEN "Error" WHEN DATEDIFF(rtime,ptime) > 72 THEN "too late" ELSE "accepted" END);
Select ptime,rtime,datediff(ptime,rtime) dif,refund from transactions;
```

To get the 2nd purchase using rank we create a query assigning rank as follows:

```
SELECT ID,
       ptime,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ptime ASC ) Rank
FROM transactions
ORDER BY ID,
         Rank;
```

Which we can then use as a CTE and use a where to only return the second record for each I'd.

```
WITH rankings AS (
SELECT ID,
       ptime,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ptime ASC ) Rank
FROM transactions
ORDER BY ID,
         Rank )
SELECT ID,ptime
FROM rankings
WHERE Rank = 2;
```

This is all very well but the request was for a virtual column and not a query.
When we try to use aggregation functions in a virtual column we get errors because the definition of a virtual column should only reference fields in the same row, of columns already declared in the table definition. (These lines are commented out to avoid blocking the script.

```
Gives an error
#ALTER TABLE transactions ADD COLUMN rank_id INT AS ( RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ptime ASC ));
#ERROR 1901 (HY000) at line 38: Function or expression 'rank()' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `rank_id`

#ALTER TABLE transactions ADD COLUMN rank_id INT AS ( RANKX(transactions.id,sum(idl)));
#ERROR 1901 (HY000) at line 41: Function or expression 'sum()' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `rank_id`

#ALTER TABLE transactions ADD COLUMN rank_id INT AS ( RANKX(transactions.id,id));
#ERROR 1901 (HY000) at line 55: Function or expression '`RANKX`()' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `rank_id`
```

It seems that some aggregation functions can be used in virtual columns some SQL engines. I've tried a few but I have yet to find one which works here.
I am wondering whether this is a "trick" question to encourage you to research the principales of virtual columns?